# Arduino: Can import library in ino, but not in C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, arduino-ide

I'm trying to use a UTFT library in Arduino. If I work with a single `.ino` file and include the library there, everything works fine, like this:

#### example.ino

```
#include <UTFT.h>
UTFT myGLCD(QD220A,A2,A1,A5,A4,A3); 
...
```

However, if I create a `.cpp` and a `.h` file, like this:

#### example.h

```
#include <UTFT.h>
```

#### example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
UTFT myGLCD(QD220A,A2,A1,A5,A4,A3); 
...
```

I get an error: UTFT does not mean a type

If I copy the whole TFT library to the project directory, and use `#include "UTFT.h"` in the `example.h` instead, the error is dismissed.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's some of the *magic* of the Arduino IDE.

Are you using `1.0.6` or the beta `1.5.X`?

Those kind of issues are being discussed on the google group and should be fixed in a near future.

In the meantime, you can give a try to the [Bare Arduino Project](https://github.com/ladislas/Bare-Arduino-Project).

The idea is to move away from the IDE, organise your project as you wish and use your favorite text editor such as vim or sublimetext with code completion and error checking.

If you have any issue using it, feel free to fill out an issue on Github ;)

Comment: Thank you for replying.I'm using the 1.0.5 for Mac,guess it's a bit old.I'll try the Bare Arduino Project u suggested, thank you again.

Comment: @NickZhang 1.0.5 is not that old. It's just the way the IDE works. A lot of improvement are coming in the next few months ;)

Comment: @NickZhang I updated the Bare Arduino Project to be able to use it with the Arduino IDE 1.6.3, check it out! :)