# Including arduino libs inside non-ino files

Tags: c++, arduino, header-files, arduino-ide

I had a larger than I'd like `.ino` file for the Arduino IDE.  So, I decided to separate it all out into various `.h` and `.cpp` files.  I am hoping to avoid the trouble of creating a makefile, by using the Arduino IDE to compile and upload my program, so I left my *main* file as a `.ino` which just includes the various headers and calls functions defined within them.  This all works fine; however, I would like to use the SPI and Keyboard/Mouse/Usb libraries in the files that I split up into `.h` and `.cpp` files.

I am able to `#include <Arduino.h>` from any of those files, but I cannot include any of the headers below, which are needed for the Keyboard and SPI library to be included:

```
#include <address.h>
#include <adk.h>
#include <confdescparser.h>
#include <hid.h>
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <hidusagestr.h>
#include <KeyboardController.h>
#include <MouseController.h>
#include <parsetools.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <usb_ch9.h>
#include <SPI.h>
```

Anyone have any idea how to get the Arduino IDE to pick up those headers when the `#include <whatever.h>` is not in the main `.ino` file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

this is a possible duplicate of this question:

[Arduino: Can import library in ino, but not in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630792/arduino-can-import-library-in-ino-but-not-in-c/27634912#27634912)

My answer was:

That's some of the *magic* of the Arduino IDE.

Are you using `1.0.6` or the beta `1.5.X`?

Those kind of issues are being discussed on the google group and should be fixed in a near future.

In the meantime, you can give a try to the [Bare Arduino Project](https://github.com/ladislas/Bare-Arduino-Project).

The idea is to move away from the IDE, organise your project as you wish and use your favorite text editor such as vim or sublimetext with code completion and error checking.

If you have any issue using it, feel free to fill out an issue on Github ;)

Comment: I'm using the Due and need 1.5.x features, so your bare arduino project will not work for me, unfortunately...